# send select value as a param to url with out submit button using ajax

Tags: php, ajax

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="area.php" method="get">
            <select name="xyz">
                <option value="1">option1</option>
                <option value="2">option2</option>
            </select>
    </body>
</html>
```

I want to send data of value of option as a param to form action with out      submit button.
I have seen ajax and jquery but submit button is required every time.

Comment: When should the parameter be sent? Something has to trigger the action. Do you want it to submit the form when a user makes a selection?

Comment: Use onChange( ) method of jquery to send the data.

Comment: yes i do not need submit button ,send option value  to form when user select the option

Answer (score 1):

I'll use jQuery syntax for its brevity. You can easily do this in native Javascript also.

Here's an abbreviated version of your form:

```
<form action="area.php" method="get" id="myform">
    <select id="myselect">
        <!-- ... options ... -->
    </select>
</form>
```

Have this Javascript run when the page is done loading (note the first line). It's important that the `.change()` be bound after the form has been rendered.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#myselect").change(function() {
        $("#myform").trigger("submit");
    });
});
```

This will fire the default submit action on the form whenever the `select` element is changed.

Comment: Excellent. Please accept my answer if it solved your problem!

Answer (score 1):

You can use ajax for that as follows:

```
$(".selectElement").on('change',function(){
    $.ajax({
     url: "area.php",
     method: "POST"
    });
});
```

You can get some documentation on this http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax

Answer (score 1):

**HTML:**

```
<form>
  <select name="xyz" id="mySelect">
    <option value="1">option1</option>
    <option value="2">option2</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(function(){

    $("#mySelect").on("change", function(){

        var getValue = $(this).val();

        $.ajax({
            url:'area.php',
            type:'get',
            data:{ selectValue:getValue },
           // get this value @area.php using $_GET['selectValue'];

            success:function(response){
                // whatever you echoed in area.php, comes in response 
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<select name="xyz" onchange="this.form.submit()">
    <option value="1">option1</option>
    <option value="2">option2</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this :

```
  <html>
        <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function call_ajax (str) {
        alert(str);
         var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
         xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
             if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                 document.getElementById("abc").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
             }
         }
         xmlhttp.open("POST", "a.php?value="+str, true);
         xmlhttp.send();
    }
</script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="a.php" method="get">
            <select name="xyz" id="abc" onchange="return call_ajax(this.value)">
                <option value="1">option1</option>
                <option value="2">option2</option>
            </select>
    </body>
</html>
```